# Перехожу с RoR на Python (Django) нужна помощь

Tags: python, django, ruby-on-rails, сервер, веб-программирование

Перехожу на Python есть вопросы :

1. У RoR есть RVM с помощью его очень легко работать с разными версиями как Руби так и Рельс, а при работе с Python такое практикуется? И какой менеджер обычно используете (если используете) ?
2. Сейчас уже можно спокойно использовать Python3 при работе с Django\Flask\Tornado или лучше 2.х ?
3. Можно использовать самую свежую версию Django (1,9) ?
4. На Windows можно нормально развернуть Python/Django проджект (хотя бы для тестов) ?
5. Чем вы обычно ещё пользуетесь используя данный стек (может какие либы, шаблонизаторы подскажите)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(вопрос-опросник, ну да ладно)

1. Для управления зависимостями можно использовать virtualenv - с помощью него можно создавать виртуальные окружения, в каждом из которых ставить разные версии пакетов (с помощью pip), независимые от пакетов системных. Насчёт версий питона не знаю: мой Arch Linux поддерживает их установку в систему без дополнительных инструментов, а virtualenv'у можно указать, какую версию использовать.
2. Да
3. Да
4. Да (но стоит быть аккуратным с особенностями ФС винды, но это уже непосредственно джанги не касается)
5. Шаблонизатор Jinja2, ибо гибче родного. Ну и в качестве плюшек django-debug-toolbar, pylint, pytest, selenium и tox (для Flask аналогично)

Answer (score 1):

1. virtualenv всем прекрасен, однако для себя использую, ИМХО, более "продвинутый" вариант - [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv);
2. можно и, опять же на мой вкус, лучше его и использовать;
3. можно;
4. можно, но я бы не стал - чаще все таки придется разворачивать это на Linux'ах, так что и осваивать лучше сразу в связке;
5. по поводу шаблонизатора и debug-библиотек - согласен с предыдущим оратором; еще можно посмотреть на следующее:

   - [django-cms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/index.html) - более чнм исчерпывающее решение, если нужна удобная CMS для одного или нескольких сайтов в проекте;
   - [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) - отличный пакет для разработки REST API;
   - [django-db-mailer](https://github.com/LPgenerator/django-db-mailer) - самая удобная из ныне найденных батареек для управлением рассылкой сообщений (там и email, и sms, и еще куча всякого).

А дальше - все зависит от конкретных задач